# Перехват http-запросов

Tags: javascript

Есть веб-приложение, написанное на `ASP.NET MVC`.
На одной html-странице подключена js-библиотека. При определенных действиях пользователя на этой странице из этой библиотеки вызывается js-скрипт, который отправляет различные http-запросы, чтобы получить необходимые данные.

Но запросы формируются следующего вида:

```
index.php?address=http://noname.net:80/services/cmp/
```

Мне нужно перехватывать эти запросы, изменять их (делать просто запрос `http://noname.net:80/services/cmp/`), после чего выполнять эти запросы и результат обратно возвращать в js-скрипт.
В самой библиотеке я не могу внести изменения в скрипт, который формирует этот запрос.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это возможно только через  [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), но  ServiceWorker'ы пока в разработке в большинстве браузеров и стандарт для них всё ещё в стадии черновика. Кроме того они работают только с HTTPS.

Comment: Выкиньте библиотеку в мусорку.